# Irritating popup re Google Calendar

Tags: 20.04, thunderbird, calendar, google

I'm frequently being prompted by a popup (initiated by Thunderbird?) to input my password for Google Calendar, even though I've removed my Gmail account (with its data) from ThunderBird though I haven't deleted the Gmail a/c as I use that a/c for my Android phone's Gmail a/c : interestingly, the popup then asks again presumably due to rejecting my correct password! Any ideas on how to stop this popup appearing or to get the password accepted by the popup?
NB Ubuntu 20.04, Thunderbird 91.7.0

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version or which Thunderbird version are you using?

Comment: If possible, post a screenshot of that dialog here: may be easier to recognize. Could be evolution.

Comment: @kanehekill Ubuntu 20.04, Thunderbird 91.7.0

Comment: @vanadium AFAIK not possible to post a screenshot on this site.

Comment: Add relevant information to your question, not in comments. Use "edit".

Comment: @vanadium Not able to add relevant information to question as it is almost at limit of number of characters.

Comment: You cannot add the info about your Ubuntu version? I have seen questions much larger than this, so character count will not be the issue here.

Comment: @JohnRose Do not add the information in the **comments**. Edit your original question and include all the information there.

Comment: @raj Have you nothing better to do than come up with pedantic comments?

Comment: I am trying to help. You said that you cannot add information due to the limit on number of characters. While there is a number of characters in a **comment**, there is **no such limit** (at least that I'm aware of) in a **question**. Therefore the proper method to add information is in the question, not in the comment.